# I need to run twice docker-compose to not have errors

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm learning to use Docker in real world developement environment, so I created a very simple "Hello World" app in Node.js, with Docker.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "docker-real-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

**server.js** (the entry point of the app):

```
var express = require('express');

express()
  .get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.send('Success');
  })
  .listen(3000, function(err) {
      if (!err) { console.log('Server started') }
  });
```

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:5.6.0

WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV development
EXPOSE 3000

ADD package.json /app
RUN npm install
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        context: .
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - /app/node_modules
    ports:
        - 80:3000
    command: node server.js
```

To summarize: In **package.json** I add *express* as a dependency to create a basic server in **server.js**. In **Dockerfile.dev** I define the image I need for this environment. Note that I copied **package.json** in the `/app` working directory and then run `npm install`. Finally, I define my environment with **docker-compose.yml**. Pretty basic (from many sources to avoid some pitfalls, like adding `/app/node_modules` in docker-compose volumes)

The problem is that running `docker-compose up` produces the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up

Building web
Step 1 : FROM mhart/alpine-node:5.6.0
 ---> cdbaa8672a25
...
...
web_1  | module.js:341
web_1  |     throw err;
web_1  |     ^
web_1  |
web_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
web_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
web_1  |     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
web_1  |     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
web_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:77)
web_1  |     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
web_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
web_1  |     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
web_1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
dockerrealworld_web_1 exited with code 1
```

And then re-running the same command (without modifying any code), it works:

```
$ docker-compose up

Starting dockerrealworld_web_1
Attaching to dockerrealworld_web_1
web_1  | Server started
```

Why doesn't it work the first time? What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you try building the images separately ?

Comment: Maybe you can educate me--what is the purpose of the /app/node_modules volume in your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: The purpose of the volume `/app/node_modules` is to preserve the stuff in container node_modules folder. Without that the other volume `.:/app` would hide/override the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. The Dockerfile needs to...

```
# Create the location of our app within the image
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the package json containing dependencies, then install
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Copy the current source to the image
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Start the service
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

You've got the write idea, but docker images take building from the ground up.